# Problema al obtener ubicación de Navigator.geolocation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, geolocalización

estoy realizando una aplicación capaz de obtener la ubicación mediante javascript desde mobile, lo que sucede es que al momento de buscar la ubicación en chrome, me arroja una ubiucación con un accuracy aproximadamente de 2km. Y así se mantiene, incluso si uso watchposition, El problema está que al abrir el mismo aplicativo en firefox me obtiene la ubi9cación exacta y luego recargo la pagina en chrome y ya me da la ubicación exacta, es algo extraño, incluso el propio google maps deja de darme la ubicación. Estoy usando vue-maps2 y este el codigo en resumen de obtener la ubicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que falta preguntar permisos y las options, pero incluso agregando eso me daba una ubicación erronea, alguien podría orientarme en por qué sucede esto?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `watchPosition` y habilitar la precisión  alta, funciona así:

```
  function success(posicion) {
  hazAlgo(posicion.coords.latitude, posicion.coords.longitude);
}

function error() {
  alert('No hay posición disponible.');
}

const opciones = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  maximumAge: 30000,
  timeout: 27000
};

const watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, opciones);
```

Donde `enableHighAccuracy` activa la precisión alta, `maximumAge` vida máxima de la coordenada de precisión, hasta ese tiempo el valor se guardará en caché, pasado ese tiempo si vuelves a esta función volverá a solicitar la posición al navegador, y `timeout` es el tiempo de espera antes de dar el error de que no encuentra la ubicación.